# My Digispark board won't show up in Ports tab in Arduino IDE (OSX)

Tags: usb, avr, compile, digispark

I bought a Digistump/Digispark board online and when i received it, I plugged it into my iMac to see if it works. I went to the apple in the top left corner and clicked "About this Mac". Then I clicked "System Report" and I went to the USB tab and it showed something connected as:

```
"Vendor-Specific Device:"
```

I was glad that it showed up but when I went to the Arduino IDE it didn't show up in the ports tab. I downloaded the AVR pack and the driver (i'm pretty sure the driver should work, if there is a specific driver that will work could someone send me to it) I am really frustrated and mad because it seems like this always happens. If someone could help me that would be greatly appreciated! Thank You.

```
Atmel 1624 tiny85
```

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is supposed to. The Digispark briefly connects in "bootloader" mode, which you spotted as "Vendor-Specific Device:".

Then after 5 seconds it runs the loaded sketch. If your sketch doesn't create a USB port (eg. a keyboard) then it will disappear from the USB list.

See:

http://digistump.com/wiki/digispark/tutorials/connecting

You don't select the port, the core files automatically find the Digispark and program it. You have to plug in the Digispark when instructed, to activate the bootloader.